# wp_head hook including file not working wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having some issue with site I am developing. Let me know you some of the pages are static php pages which are working fine. But the issue is with wordpress pages, I have all css and js files are included from header-required.php file. I am calling this header-required.php file from function file by wp_head hook. here is my code of function.php file:

```
function hook_javascript()
{
     include('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/inc/header-required.php');
} 
add_action('wp_head','hook_javascript');
```

And I am calling this function from all wordpress file code wp_head();
here is the code:

while loading, This function is calling properly, but **it does not including file header-required.php**. If i am including this file from specific wordpress file, Its working.
Please help. Thanks..

your specified path is correct. Actully I am calling this file from wordpress and header-required.php file is php file which is outside wordpress directory. example.com contain all static php pages, and inside this directory,I have created one another directory called wrpas, which contains wordpress. This some what confusing because i am using static php pages and wordpress together on one site. Another thing header and footer files are static php pages, which i am using in wordpres.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is the full path to your file? The current `include` will evaluate to http://www.example.com/inc/header-required.php , i.e in the web root folder it will look for inc/header-required.php

Comment: First of all, this is all wrong. secondly, please show your code from header-required.php

Comment: add your `header-required.php` file in header.php

Comment: @Anand:  you are righ Anand. your specified path is correct. Actully I am calling this file from wordpress and header-required.php file is php file which is outside wordpress directory.

Comment: @Anand  your specified path is correct. Actully I am calling this file from wordpress and header-required.php file is php file which is outside wordpress directory. example.com contain all static php pages, and inside this directory,I have created one another directory called wrpas, which contains wordpress. This some what confusing because i am using static php pages and wordpress together on one site. Another thing header and footer files are static php pages, which i am using in wordpres.

Answer (score 0):

Put that file in theme folder

Rather than using php include use get_template_part for wordpress

Use

```
    <?php get_template_part('header-required'); ?>
```

For more details

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Answer (score 0):

Don't include through hook because this is php file, you can directly include through include and require function in your header.php file inside the theme.